# Anyway to stub local variables in an rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have code that looks like this in a method that I am trying to test:

```
  service = if user_activator?
                SomeService.new(subscription.user, cookies: cookies)
             elsif sub_activator?
                 SomeOtherService.build(subscription: subscription, cookies: cookies)
            end
```

I am trying to stub service to be an instance of SomeService and then try to see if it receives a method with some code that looks like this:

```
expect(some_service_instance).to receive(:activate).with(hash_including(
          app_context: app_context,
          cookies: cookies,
          subscription: subscription
        ))
```

But is there a way to stub a local variable to be an instance of UserActivationService??

Here are some ways that I think may work?

First, should I extract that conditional local variable set into a method like this (this feels fishy):

```
def service
    if some_service_activator?
      SomeService.new(subscription.user, cookies: cookies)
    elsif sub_activator?
      SomeOtherService.build(subscription: subscription, cookies: cookies)
    end
  end
```

then I can do:

```
let(:some_service_instance) { SomeService.new(subscription.user, cookies: cookies) }
allow(<something that returns an instance of the class I am testing>).to receive(:service) { some_service_instance }
```

then

```
  expect(some_service_instance).to receive(:activate).with(hash_including(
          app_context: app_context,
          cookies: cookies,
          subscription: subscription
        ))
```

Is this kosher?

Comment: No, you can't stub a local. Your idea of moving the reference you need to stub to a method and returning that is the usual thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this all is taking place inside a controller I think you want to use the `@controller` variable.

```
let(:user_activation_service_instance) { UserActivationService.new(subscription.user, cookies: cookies) }
allow(@controller).to receive(:service) { user_activation_service_instance }
```